# Spring custom configuration annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to create a Annotation to enable custom Kafka configuration to construct a commons lib.
My idea with this aproach is turn easy kafka configuration for all my apps, removing all boilerplate configurations.

So I want to annotate my main application class with an annotation and do all configuration for kafka listeners and publishers.

But my configuration class is initializing after spring components and I get error: `Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' in your configuration`

My annotation:

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(KafkaListenerConfigurationSelector.class)
public @interface CustomEnableKafka {}
```

My configuration selector:

```java
public class KafkaListenerConfigurationSelector implements DeferredImportSelector {

    @Override
    public String[] selectImports(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata) {
        return new String[]{CustomKafkaAutoConfiguration.class.getName()};
    }
}
```

And finally my configuration class:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomKafkaPropertiesMap.class)
@AutoConfigureBefore({KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomKafkaAutoConfiguration {

    //my properties comming from application.yml
    private final CustomKafkaPropertiesMap propertiesMap;
    private final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postProcessBeanFactory() {
        // My logic to register beans
        propertiesMap.forEach((configName, properties) -> {
          // Configuring my factory with a bean name: myTopicKafkaProducerFactory
          var producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(senderProps(properties));
          configurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(configName + "KafkaProducerFactory", producerFactory);
    
          //Configuring my kafka template with a bean name: myTopicKafkaTemplate
          var kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
          configurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(configName + "KafkaTemplate", kafkaTemplate);
       });
    }
}
```

I don't know how can I put a priority to this configuration than another.

**Edit:**

When I `@Autowired` any bean that I registered inside my customer configuration with a qualifier `myTopicKafkaTemplate`, like:

```java
@Service
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myTopicKafkaTemplate")
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> myTopicKafkaTemplate;
}
```

Then I get an error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field myTopicKafkaTemplate in com.example.demo.service.TestService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-configuration doesn't work that way.
It cannot be imported and expected to do all that auto-configuration stuff like yours `@AutoConfigureBefore({KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})`.

Consider instead of the custom annotation to have this `CustomKafkaAutoConfiguration` configured in the `META-INF/spring.factories` file as a entry like this:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.my.project.CustomKafkaAutoConfiguration
```

**EDIT**

Thank you for sharing more info about your configuration!

So, for that `@Autowired` to work, a bean definition with respective name and type has to be registered in the application context. However your `CustomKafkaAutoConfiguration` is bean by itself and it registers those singletons during its bean initialization phase which is late for autowire candidates.

Consider to implement the `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` instead of `@PostConstruct`. It cannot be a `@Configuration` any more and it cannot do `@EnableConfigurationProperties` as well. You can move that into a separate `@Configuration` class, however in the `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` you have to use an `EnvironmentAware` - you cannot call for beans from an `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`.

Comment: Is there a way to do with annotation and the ImportSelection interface?

Comment: That way you cannot guarantee an order the classes are loaded into an application context configuration. Your `@AutoConfigureBefore` won't do any effects. It might be great if you share more about your error, because as far as I know user configuration is always loaded before an auto-configuration. So, your `@Import` must have effect first, than the rest of auto-configuration.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some code examples and logs. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.